# How to parse a json response?

Tags: c#, json

The answer comes to me like this json:

```
{"error":"Error ID","code":"invalid_id"}
```

I need to find out if there is an "error"/"errors" in the json response to throw an exception on an error. How to do it most optimally with the help of Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deserialize JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-deserialize-json-with-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a c# class that represents the json object.

For Example:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    [JsonProperty("Error")]
    public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string ErrorCode {get;set;}

}
```

Then you can desserialize the jsonText into this class, and check if Error is null or empty:

```
var response = JsonConvert.Desserialize<JsonResponse>(jsonText);
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(response.Error)) {
       Console.WriteLine("Ocorreu um erro: " + response.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use late binding with the dynamic type:

```
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"error\":\"Error ID\",\"code\":\"invalid_id\"}");

var error = response.error;
```